# What web based players out there besides JWPlayer can support load and play mutiple items in one instance?

Tags: html5-video, media-player, jwplayer, video.js, mediaelement.js

According to http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference#playlist JWPlayer can be fed with a playlist of items and supports a unified timeline. I've roughly researched a couple of alternatives such as mediaelementjs and videojs, both have "playlist" capability but not quite as JWPlayer's. Their playlist feature appears to work to support item switches without a unified timeline. What player out there does what JWPlayer does in this case?

Comment: What about JW Player is making you look for an alternative, if JW Player does what you are looking for?

Comment: Customizability of the controlbar is one reason. According to https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks/blob/master/jw6-plugin-sdk/docs/plugins.md
In JW6, plugins can only add buttons to the dock, using the Button API. The controlbar cannot be modified anymore. This restriction is added to provide end users with a clearer UX and to have JW Player behave the same across desktop browsers and devices (where built-in controls are used).

Comment: Yeah, that is something we actually want to add in a future release, as it has been asked for quite some time. Please note, we are on JW7 now, and all of the controls are entirely done with CSS, which makes customization much easier than before.

Comment: I like JW7's CSS based skins. Although what's more important for me is to find a way or a player that allows adding buttons/ controls into the controlbar so that my customized features can have a unified look & feel.

Comment: I see. That is something we want to add into a future player release.

Comment: Ethan, could you offer a release schedule?

Comment: I don't have a public release schedule I'm afraid, I don't know an ETA on this feature.